# Shiny: Concatenate inputText in Text

Tags: shiny, textinput

I want the user to complete his email address to restore the password. I need the user to populate part of his email address in a inputText that is in the same line with the rest. I want something like this:

[image]

but this is what i get:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    library(shiny)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      uiOutput("completeMailMessage")
      ,actionButton("Restore","Restore user")
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      emailAddress<-"someone@gmail.com"
      dotPosition<-tail(unlist(gregexpr("@", emailAddress)), n=1)
      
      firstPart<-substr(emailAddress,1,1)
      secondPart<-substr(emailAddress,2,dotPosition-2)
      thirdPart<-substr(emailAddress,dotPosition-1,nchar(emailAddress))
      
      
      observeEvent(input$Restore,{
        emailAddress2<-paste0(firstPart,input$b,thirdPart)
        print(emailAddress2)
        
      })
      
      output$completeMailMessage<-renderUI({
        fluidRow(
          tags$head(
            tags$style(type="text/css","label{ display: table-cell; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle; } .form-group { display: table-row;}") 
          ),
          h4("Complete the email to restore the password:"),
          div(style= " text-align: left;"
              ,tags$h5(firstPart)
              ,textInput(inputId = "b",
                        label = div(style = "font-size:10pX;", ""), value=secondPart,width = "200px")
              ,tags$h5(thirdPart)
          )  
        )    
        
      })
    
    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("completeMailMessage")
  ,actionButton("Restore","Restore user")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  emailAddress<-"someone@gmail.com"
  dotPosition<-tail(unlist(gregexpr("@", emailAddress)), n=1)
  
  firstPart<-substr(emailAddress,1,1)
  secondPart<-substr(emailAddress,2,dotPosition-2)
  thirdPart<-substr(emailAddress,dotPosition-1,nchar(emailAddress))
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Restore,{
    emailAddress2<-paste0(firstPart,input$b,thirdPart)
    print(emailAddress2)
    
  })
  
  output$completeMailMessage<-renderUI({
    fluidPage(
      
      fluidRow(h4("Complete the email to restore the password:")),
    fluidRow(
    tags$head(
          tags$style(HTML(
            ".form-control { height:auto; padding:1px 1px;}"
          ))
        ),        
        

      column(width = 1,
        div(style = "white-space: nowrap;", 
            h5(firstPart,style="display:inline-block"),
            div(style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;margin-left:0px",textInput("b", label = NULL, value = secondPart, width = 80)),
            h5(thirdPart,style="display:inline-block")
            
        )
      )
 
    )
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]